# SQL Join multiple tables using where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a sql statement:

```
Select * FROM table1
inner join table2 AS t2
  ON 
inner join table3 AS t3
  ON
inner join table4 AS t4
  ON
Where FK_Client_ID = 4
```

All tables have the client ID in common. So Not sure what to do on the `ON`.

Will it be something like `ON t2.FK_Client_ID = ......` not sure.

So I just want all the data from those tables that has FK_Client_ID in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *,
     (Select FK_Client_ID from table2 where FK_Client_ID = t1.FK_Client_ID  )As TID1,
     (Select FK_Client_ID from table3 where FK_Client_ID = t1.FK_Client_ID  )As TID2,
     (Select FK_Client_ID from table4 where FK_Client_ID = t1.FK_Client_ID  )As TID3 
FROM table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * FROM table1 t1
inner join table2 AS t2
  ON t2.FK_Client_ID = t1.FK_Client_ID
inner join table3 AS t3
  ON t3.FK_Client_ID = t1.FK_Client_ID
inner join table4 AS t4
  ON t4.FK_Client_ID = t1.FK_Client_ID
Where t1.FK_Client_ID = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

if your foreign field name is `"FK_Client_ID"` and primary key in table1 is `"Client_ID"`

```
Select * FROM table1
inner join table2 AS t2
  ON  t2.FK_Client_ID = table1.Client_ID
inner join table3 AS t3
  ON  t3.FK_Client_ID = table1.Client_ID
inner join table4 AS t4
  ON  t4.FK_Client_ID = table1.Client_ID
Where table1.Client_ID = 4
```

Since you are using inner join no matter you join them with `table1` or any other of them

Comment: The above query will result in Ambiguous column name 'FK_Client_ID'.

Comment: You have mentioned the primary key column as 'Client_ID' in table1,hence the 'where' condition should be table1.Client_ID or alias of other tables (t2 or t3 or t4).FK_Client_ID

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
     ON t1.FK_Client_ID = t2.FK_Client_ID 
        inner join table3 t3
     ON t1.FK_Client_ID = t3.FK_Client_ID
         inner join table4 t4
     ON t1.FK_Client_ID = t4.FK_Client_ID
 Where t1.FK_Client_ID = 4
```